# Writing a prediction equation from plsr model

Tags: r

Greeting to everyone.

I sucessfully computed pls-r model in R using the code below

```
pls_modB_Kexch_2 <- plsr(Av.K_exc~., data = trainKexch.sar.veg, scale=TRUE,method= "s",validation='CV')
```

The regression coeffiecents for ncomps =11 were

```
(

    Intercept)= -4.692966e+05, 
    Easting   =   6.068582e+03, Northings= 7.929767e+02, 
 sigma_vv =    8.024741e+05, sigma_vh =   -6.375260e+05, 
 gamma_vv =  -7.120684e+05, gamma_vh =    4.330279e+05, 
 beta_vv  =  -8.949598e+04, beta_vh  =    2.045924e+05,
 c11_db    =   2.305016e+01, c22_db     = -4.706773e+01,
 c12_real   = -1.877267e+00.)
```

It predicts well new data sets when applied with in R enviroment.

My challenge is presenting this model in form of y=sum(AX)+Bo equation where A are coeffiecents of respective variablesX
Or any other mathmetical form, that can be presented academically.

I tried a direct way by multiplying the coeff.to each variable and suming them up, aquick manual trial for predictions gave me strange results. Am missing something here, please help.

Comment: Generally packages that provide regression functions also provide prediction methods for models. You have not included code to load a package so we cannot really know which of the multiple possible packages you are using. (And if you are using a package that is not currently on CRAN, you should provide code taht will install such a package.)

Comment: I used  `library(pls)` package

Comment: It has a predict function. (I read the manual.)